# How to hide source code from html using php

Tags: php

Ok, so I am making a website in the Minecraft area. This area is EXTREMELY competitive! So when I am a top class Minecraft Server/Graphics person and I want to sell my knowledge, I don't want people stealing my source. I know that if you use PHP and you view the source, just a blank source code page pops up. And please don't tell me I need to code my page in PHP, because I honestly don't know much about it. I tried doing

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://mysite.com/websitecode.html');
echo $page
?>
```

but that still showed the source code whenever I clicked CTRL+U. I really don't want people stealing my stuff, because then other people do it for cheaper, which kills me. Please help, if their is any other way I can disable the source code from being seen by anyone, please tell me!

Comment: If a user has access to the data and wants to copy it, they WILL be able to copy it, no matter what. There has never been a foolproof DRM scheme.

Comment: exactly how can a browser render a page if there's no html to render? your "empty" php page probably just has a few hundred blank lines to make it look like there's nothing there - did you look to see if there's a scrollbar?

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent anything that needs to be outputted to the browser from being stolen by the user. The best you can do is obfuscate it, but to anyone with any determination at all can easily circumvent that.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed you cannot hide hide HTML source served to the browser.

One way to achieve something close to what you want to do will be to serve a page with only one AJAX call to get the the source from your php script.

And if you really want to make things complicated, your AJAX call can return an encrypted version of the html that you will decrypt with some obfuscated javascript.

Of course this is not bulletproof as any user will have access to your javascripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide source codes, atleast not in the way you mean it, instead use clever way of hidding your css files, which will make it a bit, only a bit harder to get the contents if one is has experience and all

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean hide html? You can enocde it but you can not hide it. What page will render if there is no html.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent users from seeing your HTML code.

When a browser requests your page from a server, the server sends the HTML code to the browser, and the browser figures out how to display everything on the page. Therefore, the browser will always receive the HTML code- and as such, it's up to the browser to prevent a user from seeing that code, not you. And considering all major browsers allow the viewing of source code, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to hide the html page code from users sadly, I too was wondering about this sometime ago. Your server side code is safe but any HTML format is going to be displayed for the DOM